# Fastest way to slice a ndarray

Tags: python, performance, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I have some event data from a HDF5 file:

```
>>> events
<class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
```

I get the array data like so:

```
>>> events = events[:]
```

And the structure is like so:

```
>>> type(events)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> events.shape
(273856,)
>>> type(events[0])
<type 'numpy.void'>
>>> events[0]
(0, 30, 3523, 5352)
>>> # More information on structure 
>>> [type(e) for e in events[0]]    
[<type 'numpy.uint64'>, 
 <type 'numpy.uint32'>, 
 <type 'numpy.float64'>, 
 <type 'numpy.float64'>]   
>>> events.dtype 
[('start', '<u8'), 
 ('length', '<u4'), 
 ('mean', '<f8'), 
 ('variance', '<f8')]
```

I need to get the largest index of a particular event where the first field is less than some value. The brute force approach is:

```
>>> for i, e in enumerate(events):
>>>     if e[0] >= val:
>>>         break
```

The first index of the tuple is sorted so I can do bisection so speed things up:

```
>>> field1 = [row[0] for row in events]
>>> index = bisect.bisect_right(field1, val)
```

This show improvement but `[row[0] for row in event]` is slower than I expected. Any ideas on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, iterating over numpy arrays as you're currently doing is relatively slow. Normally, you'd use slicing instead (which creates a view, rather than copying the data into a list).

It looks like you have an object array. This will make things even slower. Do you really need an object array? It looks like all of the values are `int`s.  (Is this a "vlen" hdf5 dataset?)

The use case where an object array would make sense is if you have a different number of items in each element of `events`.  If you don't, then there's no reason to use one.

If you were using a 2D array of ints instead of an object array of tuples, you'd just do:

```
field1 = events[:,0]
```

However, in that case, you could just do: (`searchsorted` uses bisection)

```
index = np.searchsorted(events[:,0], val)
```

---

**Edit**

Ah! Okay, you have a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html). In other words, it's an array (1D, in this case) where *each item* is a C-like struct.  From:

```
>>> events.dtype 
[('start', '<u8'), 
 ('length', '<u4'), 
 ('mean', '<f8'), 
 ('variance', '<f8')]
```

...we can see that the first field is named "start".

Therefore, you just want:

```
index = np.searchsorted(events["start"], val)
```

In more general terms, if we didn't know the name of the field, but knew that it was a structured array of some sort, you'd do (paring things down to just the slicing step):

```
events[event.dtype.names[0]]
```

---

As far as whether or not it's a good idea to convert everything to a "normal" 2D array of ints, that depends on your use case.  For basic slicing and calling `searchsorted`, there's no reason to.  There shouldn't (untested) be any significant speed increase.

Based on what you're doing at the moment, I'd just leave it as is.

However, structured arrays are often cumbersome to deal with.

There are plenty of cases where structured arrays are very useful (e.g. reading in certain binary formats from disk), but if you want to think of it as a "table-like" array, you'll quickly hit pain points.  You're often better off storing the columns as separate arrays.  (Or better yet, use a `pandas.DataFrame` for "tabular" data.)

If you did want to convert it to a 2D array of ints, do:

```
events = np.hstack([events[name] for name in events.dtype.names])
```

This will automatically find a compatible datatype (`int64`, in this case) for the new array and "stack" the fields of the structured array into columns in a 2D array.

Calling `events = events.astype(int)` will effectively just yield the first column. (This is because *each item* of events is a C-like struct, and `astype` operates element-wise, so each struct is converted to a single int.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
>>> a = np.arange(10000).reshape(2500,4)
>>> np.searchsorted(a[:,0], 1000)
250
```

**Timing comparisons**:

```
>>> %timeit np.searchsorted(a[:,0], 1000)
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.7 µs per loop
>>> %timeit field1 = [row[0] for row in a];bisect.bisect_right(field1, 1000)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.63 ms per loop
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it!  However, it looks like the OP has an object array instead of a "normal" 2D array. Therefore, slicing won't work.

Comment: It's not just the speed. The OP has a one-dimensional array. Doing `a[:,0]` won't work. The OP's array may be the equivalent of `a = np.array([(1, 2), (3, 4, 5)])`.

Comment: @JoeKington Ah! I see what you meant there. ;-)

Comment: Yes @JoeKington is right. I get my data by reading a HDF5 file using h5py which gives my this format. I guess converting would also be slow.

Comment: @sudo_O If you're searching items multiple times then a one time conversion will surely improve overall time.

Comment: @sudo_O - Converting may be quite fast, but it's hard to say from what you've posted. What format is the HDF file? (I know it's hdf, but what format is the datatype? Is this a variable-length array?)  Also, what does `print events.dtype` yield (before you read it into the numpy array with `events=events[:]`)? Using a 2D array would be much more efficient, but if you're dealing with a variable-length array in the hdf file, that's not an option.

Comment: I only read in the data. I never write back or add anything to `data` if that is what you mean. The format of the file is `fast5`. I have added more information on the types to the question.

Comment: @sudo_O - The new information helps a lot, thanks! (I was thrown off by the `void` dtype.)  You just want `events["start"]`.

Comment: Thanks both for the help +1 to each. @JoeKington I am seeing great scalability now, thank you! Is it worth coverting to the lowest common data type or do you think you correct solution will be fastest?

Comment: @sudo_O - Probably not, but I added a bit to my answer to elaborate on that point.